# Why are there no significant female characters in "Reservoir Dogs"?

Tags: analysis, reservoir-dogs

After watching ‘Reservoir Dogs’, a 1992 American neo-noir crime film written and directed by Quentin Tarantino about a group of diamond thieves whose heist goes wrong, I couldn’t help but notice the absence of significant female characters.

Comment: The close vote is entirely baseless and without merit; this is a reasonably good question.

Comment: The acting credits to the film mention 2 women, played by Linda Kaye and Suzanne Celeste, plus others on the radio; there are also other uncredited female actors. Do you mean why is none of the gang female?

Comment: I understood it as '*important character*', I don't think an extra (F) who will appear a few seconds in one of the scenes is a '*female character/female actor*'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Tarantino said of this decision, "*There were no female characters in Reservoir Dogs because the movie took place over the course of an hour in this warehouse after this robbery. These guys aren't going to bring their girlfriends to the robbery. Joe didn't happen to hire any women.*"

Source : [27 Things You Didn't Know About Reservoir Dogs](https://whatculture.com/film/27-things-you-didnt-know-about-reservoir-dogs?page=12)

There are also some interesting reading about QT, women and violence: 1. [Quentin Tarantino’s take on women and violence](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2019/jul/26/quentin-tarantinos-take-on-women-and-violence). 2. [Recasting Reservoir Dogs With An All-Female Cast](https://screenrant.com/reservoir-dogs-recast-all-female-actors/). 3. [The Reservoir Dogs Feminist Analysis](https://www.ipl.org/essay/The-Reservoir-Dogs-Feminist-Analysis-P372S7QMUXFT). There are weak or strong women in his movies, good and bad women too, and I've heard people taking sides about QT, saying he's (or isn't) sexist. One has to make its own mind about that though...